# How to check if .htaccess (url rewrite) works properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is the .htaccess file. I need to check if this file is working correctly but I don't know the method to test it. Any suggestion?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crown/

AddType text/xml .xslt
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Files *.xslt>
    SetHandler text/xml
</Files>

<IfModule !mod_php4.c>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>

        # PHP is in CGI Mode, so we need a different mod_rewrite

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !categories\.php
        RewriteRule ^categories(.*) categories.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !articles\.php
        RewriteRule ^articles(.*)$ articles.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pages\.php
        RewriteRule ^pages(.*)$ pages.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blogs\.php
        RewriteRule ^blogs(.*)$ blogs.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !search.php
        RewriteRule ^search(.*)$ search\.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !authors.php
        RewriteRule ^authors(.*)$ authors\.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !articlerss.php
        RewriteRule ^articlerss(.*)$ articlerss\.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !news.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newsrss.php
        RewriteRule ^news(.*)$ news.php?$1 [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !contact.php
        RewriteRule ^contact(.*)$ contact\.php?$1 [L]


    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>

        # Using PHP 5 in module mode

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} categories.*
        RewriteRule ^categories(.*)$ categories.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} articles.*
        RewriteRule ^articles(.*)$ articles.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} pages.*
        RewriteRule ^pages(.*)$ pages.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blogs.*
        RewriteRule ^blogs(.*)$ blogs.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} search.*
        RewriteRule ^search(.*)$ search.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} authors.*
        RewriteRule ^authors(.*)$ authors.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} articlerss.*
        RewriteRule ^articlerss(.*)$ articlerss.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} news.*
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newsrss
        RewriteRule ^news(.*)$ news.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} contact.*
        RewriteRule ^contact(.*)$ contact.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    </IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php4.c>

    # PHP 4 in module mode

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} categories.*
    RewriteRule ^categories(.*)$ categories.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} articles.*
    RewriteRule ^articles(.*)$ articles.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} pages.*
    RewriteRule ^pages(.*)$ pages.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blogs.*
    RewriteRule ^blogs(.*)$ blogs.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} search.*
    RewriteRule ^search(.*)$ search.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} authors.*
    RewriteRule ^authors(.*)$ authors.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} articlerss.*
    RewriteRule ^articlerss(.*)$ articlerss.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} news.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newsrss
    RewriteRule ^news(.*)$ news.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} contact.*
    RewriteRule ^contact(.*)$ contact.php?$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was related to an [earlier message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298778/mod-rewrite-problem). In the end, the problem was in server, administrators upgraded apache server which changed something in configuration. When following line was added, url rewriting worked again:

```
Options -MultiViews
```